# Parallel transport preserves Lie bracket

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields, lie-derivative

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $\sigma(t)$ a geodesic on $M$. I'll write $\Pi_{t_0}^{t_1}$ for the parallel transport from $\sigma(t_0)$ to $\sigma(t_1)$ and $[\cdot, \cdot]$ for the Lie bracket on vector fields.

1. Is it true that $\Pi_{t_0}^{t_1}([X,Y])=[\Pi_{t_0}^{t_1}(X), \Pi_{t_0}^{t_1}(Y)]$ for $X,Y$ vector fields in $M$?
2. If not, there exists a local frame of $M$ having that property?

For my final purposes, I am  interested on veryfing that if $[X,Y]$ vanishes, so does $[\Pi_{t_0}^{t_1}(X), \Pi_{t_0}^{t_1}(Y)]$, but if the property holds in more general settings would be great.

EDITED:
As Didier pointed out, $[\Pi_{t_0}^{t_1}(X), \Pi_{t_0}^{t_1}(Y)]$ is not well defined since $\Pi_{t_0}^{t_1}(X)$ is a vector field along $\sigma$ (and possibly not extendable).

So lets try doing the following. Take an arbitrary basis $\{\dot{\sigma}(0),e_1,...,e_n\}$ where $dimM=n+1$. So consider $c: (-\epsilon, \epsilon)\rightarrow M$ a curve such that $\dot{c}(0)=e_i$ and take the variation through geodesics given by $\Gamma(s,t)=exp_{c(s)}(t\xi_{c(s)})$. On this variation define a local frame in the following way: parallel transport $\{\dot{\sigma}(0),e_1,...,e_n\}$ firstly along $c(s)$ and secondly along the main curves $\Gamma_s(t)$. Then we have a local frame defined on the $2$-manifold given by the variation, and we can compute here $[\Pi_{t_0}^{t_1}(e_i), \Pi_{t_0}^{t_1}(e_j)]$ (I know, it is only defined on the variation). So the question in this case is: can I choose a basis $\{\dot{\sigma}(0),e_1,...,e_n\}$ such that both Lie brackets (${e_i,e_j}$ and $[\Pi_{t_0}^{t_1}(e_i), \Pi_{t_0}^{t_1}(e_j)]$) vanish?[image]

Comment: How do you define $[X,Y]$ for $X,Y\in T_{\sigma(t_0)}M$? They are tangent vectors, not vector fields.

Comment: You're right, I corrected it.

Comment: Now, how do you define the Lie bracket of the two parallel transports of $X$ and $Y$, which are no longer vector fields, but vector fields along $\sigma$ (and possibly non extendable)?

Comment: Mm I see. What if I do the following: take a basis of $T_{\sigma(t_0)}$, namely $\{\dot{\sigma}(0),e_1,...,e_n\}$, and a smooth curve $c(s): (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow M$ such that $\dot{c}(0)=e_i \perp \dot{\sigma}(0)$ and construct a variation through geodesics by $\text{exp}_{c(s)}(t\xi_{c(s)})$. Then on this variation I define a local frame by parallel transporting the basis $\{\dot{\sigma}(0),e_1,...,e_n\}$ firstly along $c(s)$ and secondly alongthe main curves of the variation. Then I have a local frame of vector fields on the variation.

Comment: So the question now is if I can choose a basis such that when constructed such frame, both Lie brackets vanish.

Comment: You should edit your question since it is not clear at all that was what you meant!